# Homotopy on abstract simplicial complexes vs simplicial sets

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-complex

Suppose $\Sigma$ is an abstract simplicial complex, suppose the vertices are ordered, and let $\tilde{\Sigma}$ be the corresponding simplicial set, where the set of $k$-simplices of $\tilde{\Sigma}$ is the set of $k$-simplices of $\Sigma$, with the obvious face and degeneracy operators. How are the notions of contiguity (as in Spanier, Algebraic Topology, Chapter 3, Section 5) and homotopy in $\mathbf{sSet}$ (as in Goerss and Jardine, Simplicial Homotopy Theory, p. 23) related?

Specifically, consider the abstract simplicial complex on three points $0,1,2$ given by
$\Sigma = \{\{0\},\{1\},\{2\}, \{n,n+1\}\}$, for $n \in \{0,1\}$, i.e. the linear graph on three points. The definition in Spanier gives that the identity is contiguous to the constant map $c(\sigma) = \{0\}, \sigma \in \Sigma$. However, I don't see how the definition in Goerss and Jardine gives the corresponding conclusion. Nevertheless, if one considers the simplicial set given by $ST(\tilde{\Sigma})$, where $T$ is the geometric realization functor and $S$ is the singular functor, then I see how one can construct a homotopy between the identity on $ST(\tilde{\Sigma})$ and the constant function, but it seems odd that this wouldn't work directly in $\tilde{\Sigma}$. Is it really the case that $\tilde{\Sigma}$ is not homotopy equivalent to a point in $\mathbf{sSet}$?

Similarly, how does one see that the abstract simplicial complex given by $\mathbb{Z} \cup_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} \{n,n+1\}$ (or the corresponding simplicial set) - whose geometric realization is $\mathbb{R}$ - is homotopy equivalent to a point, as the definition in Spanier only allows for a finite sequence of simplicial maps in the definition of contiguity, and Goerss and Jardine only allow for a single simplicial map in the definition of simplicial homotopy.

Comment: If $\Sigma$ is an abstract simplicial complex, there is no *canonica*l associated simplicial set. You need some additional ingredient, e.g. an ordering of the vertices of $\Sigma$ to get face operators $d_i$ and degeneracy operators $s_j$.

Comment: True, but you can always order the vertices, and the issue already appears in the examples I gave above, where the order is given. I've edited the question to address this. Thanks!

Comment: Simplicial homotopy behaves badly as Goerss and Jardine mention right after defining it. It fails to be reflexive for even the simplest examples. One point of homotopy theory is moving from places where homotopy behaves badly to places where it behaves well. For simplicial sets, we want to move to Kan complexes. Let me note however that the homotopy types of your two objects are the same because homotopy type is, funnily enough, not determined by the relation of homotopy.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain the last sentence?

Comment: @APR What homotopy theorists have found amazingly useful is to put "homotopy equivalences" as the more fundamental object than the relation of homotopy among maps. This means that the most bare bones place homotopy theorists do homotopy is in a category $C$ with a subcategory containing all the same objects $W$. $W$ is meant to be the "homotopy equivalences" or rather weak equivalences, and it should contain all isomorphisms. In the case of simplicial sets, the weak equivalences are defined as those that geometrically realize to homotopy equivalence of spaces.

Comment: You can add more structure, namely that of a model category and then it becomes possible to relate these weak equivalences to an actual notion of homotopy, but one has to restrict to a smaller subcategory (that does not contain all objects). In the case of simplicial sets, the graph you describe does not live in this subcategory, but $ST$ of it does.